# Functionalizing iron oxide nanoparticles for antimicrobial activity

Tags: biophysics, nanoscience, applied-physics

I'm working on my thesis which is about synthesis of iron oxide nanoparticles from a plant leaf extract and testing the particles activity on bacteria to measure their toxicity towards it. The thing is we didn't get any results and it's concerning because it should give a somewhat noticeable antibacterial effect, so after that I went and searched for what's called functionalization of the nanoparticles to make them functional and found a few methods but these methods don't sound really doable in the sense that the lab I'm working in doesn't really have cutting edge tools, so you guys see the problem?

What I'm asking is did anybody fall into the same pitfall? Do you guys know, or better tried in the past any cost-effective functionalizing methods for iron oxide nanoparticles to make them functional towards bacteria?

Comment: I'm not a scientist (I'm just mathematician and contributor of the site). Welcome, I think that if you add more details these could to draw the attention of physicists of the site. For example consider **to add the literature that is relevant** in your work, I found *Biologically synthesized iron nanoparticles (FeNPs) from Phoenix dactylifera have anti-bacterial activities*, by Faryal Batool, Muhammad Shahid Iqbal, Salah-Ud-Din Khan, Javed Khan, Bilal Ahmed & Muhammad Imran Qadir, Nature Scientific Reports **11** November 2021, Article number: 22132 (2021). Or **add tags** as (biophysics)...

Comment: Would [chemistry.se] be a better home for this question?